# How to get value this type in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to get value this type in rails 4? 
what is type this structure? 
hash?

```
[#<Menu menu_name: "test", menu_price: "test", menu_etc: "", store_id: 1, menu_id: 6>]
```

i want get a "menu_id" value. and change to type integer.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array of ActiveRecord objects (Menus) so there are many ways to get the menu_id which is already an integer from the first item like

```
menus = [#<Menu menu_name: "test", menu_price: "test", menu_etc: "", store_id: 1, menu_id: 6>]
menus.first.menu_id
```

or

```
menus[0].menu_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an `ActiveRecord` in an array. Assume you have:

```
data = [#<Menu menu_name: "test", menu_price: "test", menu_etc: "", store_id: 1, menu_id: 6>]
```

You can use `data.first.menu_id.to_i` to get the integer value of `menu_id`